# css with object tag

Tags: html, css, object

I'm trying to center a pdf file in the middle of my web page, but it's not letting me set the margin's to 0 auto, like it does for normal content.

I can achieve this with absolute positioning, but why is the normal margin property not working?

```
<html>
<style>
#ob{
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
}
#wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<object id="ob" class="pdf" data="my_pdf_file.pdf" type="application/pdf">
Your browser does not support PDFs
</object>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This Link hope help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478120/how-to-set-fit-width-when-embedding-pdf-in-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are trying to center using the margin technique needs to have a width defined.

Try setting a width for the wrapper, or simply apply the margin:0 px to #ob

Comment: The OP did define a width on the object.

Comment: Adding height/width to both the object and wrapper, then applying the margin: 0 auto to the wrapper works. But for some reason doesn't work if I apply the margin property to the object. Hmm, well the first solution works, so I won't worry about the second problem.

Answer (score 1):

Give the wrapper a width, thats why its not centering i doesont know what to be compared in the center

```
#wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
text-align:center;
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4VBnC/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You're centering the wrapper, which will be 100% width, so already centered. Move the margin code to the object and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace your style tag to this one and it will solved your problem, for details please look into the comments that I wrote inside the code.

```
<style>
    #wrapper{
        width: 800px;   // It will set the width of the wraper
        margin: 0 auto;     // It will help the wrapper div to be centered of the document.
    }

    #ob{
        width: 100%;    // It will be streched upto the wrapper fixed width which is 800px
        height: 800px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<center>
<object id="ob" class="pdf" data="my_pdf_file.pdf" type="application/pdf">
Your browser does not support PDFs
</object>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: The center tag was deprecated about 100 years ago. Don't use it.

Comment: best practices will always trump shortcuts