# Chrome PDF Viewer Fit To Page

Tags: google-chrome, pdf-viewer

I have a user that open hundreds of PDFs per week through the PTO’s Electronic Filing System and need to review them in the browser.  When Firefox isn’t working with the PTO (I was able to customize Firefox), I have to use Chrome.  To manually have to click on every PDF so that I can then go through them page-by-page is not practical.  Is there a way to not have to manually fix the page layout every single time I open a pdf. I want to set the default to fit page mode so that I don’t have to do that the hundreds of times I open PDFs in the browser.

Can change this with javascript or PS?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question here: [How to set fit width when embedding pdf in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478120/how-to-set-fit-width-when-embedding-pdf-in-chrome/71951975#71951975)

It requires creating an iframe, so it may not be ideal, but my solution provides some reusable code that I use on my websites. HTH!